RustのMutexがドロップされる条件について
RustのMutexがドロップされる条件について、教えていただけないでしょうか。
The Rust Programming Language を基にRustについて勉強しています。
マルチスレッドのサーバを実装している中で、以下のコードが出てきました。
let job = receiver.lock().unwrap().recv().unwrap();

なお、receiver: Arc<Mutex<mpsc::Receiver<渡したい匿名関数>>>です
本の説明によると、上記のコードではlet job文が終わると同時にドロップされるとありましたが、
最初にMutexが説明された際は、スコープを抜けるとドロップされるとあったため混乱しています。
さらに以下のように書き換えたところ、スコープを抜けるまでドロップされなかったため
なおさら動作が分からなくなりました。
let job = receiver.lock().unwrap();
let job = job.recv().unwrap();

ドロップの条件はlockメソッドが返すMutexGuradのライフタイムに基づくと
あったのですが、どういった条件でライフタイムが変わるのでしょうか。
お手数ですが、ご教示ください。

式の途中では一時的な値というものが生じます。
簡単な例として
let foo = 1+2+5;

という文があったとするとまず 1+2 が計算されて 3 になり、 3 と 5 が足し算されて 8 が生まれてそれが foo に入ります。 このとき 3 は変数と結びついていません。 変数のスコープとして説明できない存在です。 こういった一時的なものがいつ解体されるのかは Temporary scope という概念で説明されます。 この場合は文全体の末尾が寿命の終わりです。
質問の例に当てはめると lock が返した値を変数に入れなければ解体されるのは文の終わりですが、変数に入れたなら変数のスコープが寿命です。

以下の場合、最後の戻り値以外（途中のMutexGuard等）は一時的なオブジェクトなので、その文の末尾でドロップされてunlockされます。
let job = receiver.lock().unwrap().recv().unwrap();

それに対して以下の場合は、MutexGuardをjobとして保持しているため、そのオブジェクトがドロップされるまで（スコープを抜けるまで）、unlockされません。
let job = receiver.lock().unwrap();

